# Why my state is undefined on refresh? React Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on my first app. I put response from the server in an empty array in the state, but when I try to work with this array it throws undefined. On the first render everything seems OK but any futher manipulations fail. Please, help. I'm desperate here. My code:

App component:

```
import { React, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { getExchangeCourse } from "./api/currencyApi";
import { ADD_CURRENCY } from "./reducer/currencyReducer";
import { CurrenciesConverterContextComponent } from "./context/Context";
import Header from "./components/Header";

function App() {
  const [, dispatch] = useContext(CurrenciesConverterContextComponent);

  useEffect(() => {
    getExchangeCourse().then(data => dispatch({
      type: ADD_CURRENCY,
      payload: data
    }))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Header component:

```
export default function Header() {
    const [{currencies}] = useContext(CurrenciesConverterContextComponent);

    let USD = currencies.find(e => e.cc === "USD");
    let EUR = currencies.find(e => e.cc === "EUR");
    let GBP = currencies.find(e => e.cc === "GBP");

    **these functions above work on a first render and then fail**

    return (
        <div className='converter-header'>
          <span>{USD.cc} : {USD.rate}</span>
          <span>{EUR.cc} : {EUR.rate}</span>
          <span>{GBP.cc} : {GBP.rate}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Reducer:

```
export const initialState = {
    currencies: [],
}

export const ADD_CURRENCY = '[CURRENCIES] Add Currency';

export const currenciesReducer = ( state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_CURRENCY:
            return {
                ...state,
                // currencies: [...state.currencies, action.payload]
                currencies: action.payload
            };
        default: {
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }
}
```

API request:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const currencyAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json',
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
})

export async function getExchangeCourse() {
    const {data} = await currencyAPI.get()
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Because your don't save it anywhere

Comment: How so? I thought, dispatching data in the state is saving it, am I wrong?

Comment: When you refresh the page entire JavaScript is wiped out. You have to use localStorage or backend